# Удалил логи, как вернуть возможность логирования?

Tags: centos, логирование, isp

Установлена панель ISP Manager. Копался в файлах панели, и наткнулся на папку `/var/www/www-root/data/logs/` как я понял в ней все логи сайтов и ошибок, подумал что удалю эти файлы все, и потом когда пойдут запросы они создадутся заново, но увы это так не работает. Они не создаются сами и при перезагрузке сервера. Пробовал сам создать с таким названием, они появляются в панели просмотра логов, но не записываются в них данные. Вопрос, как вернуть логи, видимо нужно выставить правильные права записи и владельца, когда удалял не обратил внимание какой там стоял, помогите вернуть возможность логирования.

Comment: Не знаю, кто что туда пишет, но обычно логи действительно создаются сами. Ели проблема с правами доступа, можно попробовать выдать каталогу `logs` права 777 (временно! это не очень безопасно, после проверки поставить более безопасные права) и посмотреть, создаст ли кто-нибудь что-нибудь в таком случае

Comment: @andreymal да я так тоже пробовал, ничего не не писало, если права не те ставить вообще не отображались, я нашел другое решение которое указал в ответе на свой вопрос, извините за беспокойство и спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решил сам, просто в управлении WWW доменами, в начале отключил логи, потом включил и они заново создались, все нужные файлы с нужными правами.

Если кому вдруг пригодится там были права

```
site.ru.access.log [640] root (владелец) www-root (группа)
site.ru.error.log [660] root (владелец) www-root (группа)
```

Ну или как я сделал через управление WWW доменами.